# impresspages after installation Fatal error: Uncaught exception

Tags: impresspages

I try install Impresspages on my hosting but after installation have:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Ip\Exception\View' with message 'View view/widget.php not found.' in /Ip/Functions.php:887 Stack trace: #0 /Ip/Internal/Content/Model.php(272): ipView('view/widget.php', Array) #1 /Ip/Internal/Content/Model.php(35): Ip\Internal\Content\Model::_generateWidgetPreview(Array, false) #2 /Ip/Internal/Content/PublicController.php(17): Ip\Internal\Content\Model::generateBlock('main', '13', 0, false) #3 [internal function]: Ip\Internal\Content\PublicController->index() #4 /Ip/Internal/Core/Job.php(126): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #5 [internal function]: Ip\Internal\Core\Job::ipExecuteController_70(Array) #6 /Ip/Internal/Dispatcher/JobDispatcher.php(39): call_user_func('\Ip\Internal\Co...', Array) #7 /Ip/Dispatcher.php(101): Ip\Internal\Dispatcher\JobDispatcher->handle('ipExecuteContro...', Array) #8 /Ip/Functions.php(368): Ip\Dispatcher->job('ipExecuteContro...', Array) #9 /Ip/Application.php(301): ipJob('ipExecuteContro...', Array) #10 /Ip/Application.php(319): Ip\Application->_handleOnlyR in /Ip/Functions.php on line 887
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I could think of right now is that file upload to the server has failed. Try reupload Ip folder.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.
Problem solved.
The problem was in the server settings.